# Pacemaker: dynamic location constraints

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I have a corosync cluster involving several machines that have different roles within the cluster.
I have some clone resources grouped together and I set up everything to behave as an opt-in cluster:

```
node dir01
node dir02
node ms01
node ms02
node ms03
primitive pri_clvmd lsb:clvm \
    op monitor interval="120" timeout="20" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="30" \
    op stop interval="0" timeout="30"
primitive pri_dlm ocf:pacemaker:controld \
    op monitor interval="120" timeout="30" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="90" \
    op stop interval="0" timeout="100"
group grp_cluster_storage pri_dlm pri_clvmd
clone cln_cluster_storage grp_cluster_storage \
    meta ordered="true" interleave="true" target-role="Started"
location LOC_CLUSTER-STORAGE1 cln_cluster_storage inf: ms01
location LOC_CLUSTER-STORAGE2 cln_cluster_storage inf: ms02
location LOC_CLUSTER-STORAGE3 cln_cluster_storage inf: ms03
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.1.7-ee0730e13d124c3d58f00016c3376a1de5323cff" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    expected-quorum-votes="3" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    last-lrm-refresh="1390076650" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    symmetric-cluster="false"
```

So far, so good, everything seems to work just fine at that stage however one of the thing I want to acheive is to be able to add hosts in the cluster without having to modify the cib configuration.
With the above config, whenver I need a new host (let's say ms04), I would have to add a new location constraint.

Is there any way around that?

Comment: Why do you create location constraints? Why not let the cluster determine by itself where to host which resources?

Comment: because it is an asymetric cluster and machines have different hardware specs based on what they are supposed to do. For instance all of them doesn't have an HBA to access the SAN, or they have different CPU and RAM sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kind of an answer to my own question:

what I am trying to do is probably not painless at the moment. however, forthcoming pacemaker should show that by implementing support for region x in location constraints:

Quoted from http://blog.clusterlabs.org/blog/2013/announcing-1-dot-1-11-beta-testing/

"PE: Allow location constraints to take a regex pattern to match against resource IDs"